# express and angular : how to make the file extension change dynamically when downloading it from a server directory

Tags: angularjs, node.js, multer

Sorry if don't make any sense here.
I am using `multer` and storing files such as .docx or .pdf etc in my server. But I am able to retrieve these only when i give their original extension, I want to make a way in which the extension comes dynamically.
I am using this to download the file(as I know the file is .docx). But how to retrieve it if it was stored as .pdf.`

```
a(href="/assets/img/profile/{{doctor._id}}.docx") Download
```

My angular controller where i get the file from my server

```
fd.append("file", $scope.files[0]);
$scope.decachedImageUrl = "/assets/img/profile/" + $scope.doctor._id + ".docx";      
fd.append("data",
        angular.toJson({ doctorId: sharedService.getDoctorId() } )) ;
      $http.post("/doctors/" + sharedService.getDoctorId() + "/photos", fd, {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
        transformRequest: angular.identity
       }).success(function (){
            $scope.decachedImageUrl = "/assets/img/profile/" + $scope.doctor._i + ".docx" +'?decache=' + Math.random();
            usSpinnerService.stop('spinner-1');
```

So is there a way to do it.

Comment: will you have unique file names?? excluding the extension

Comment: but can you tell me what to do with the extension

Comment: Dont pass the extension at all if your files have unique names.. Just in your server code select by file name.

Comment: does not work gives 404

Comment: it depends on how you handle in your server side right?? why dont you build this `/assets/img/profile/{{doctor._id}}.docx` dynamically. Just make a server call  by passing the file name and get back its extension and then build the anchor tag href right?